# Remove dropdownlist one by one while is added

Tags: jquery, html

Is it a way to remove dropdownlist one by one?

i'm using jquery to create and append dropdownlist with button in div, the button is use for delete dropdownlist.

**Requirement:**

1. Able delete dropdownlist one by one.

Here is a snippet showing the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAddItem").click(function(){
    var text = $('#ddl_device_option').val();  
    if(text == "device_1"){
      $('#dvTable').append('<font face="Arial" size="4"> </font>&nbsp;');
      $('#dvTable').append(text);
      $('#dvTable').append(' <select id="test"> <option>1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option> <option>8</option> </select> ');

      var i = "1";
      $('#dvTable').append('<input type="button" id='+ i +' value="x" class="btn btn-danger" >');
    } else if(text == "device_2") {
      $('#dvTable').append('<font face="Arial" size="4"> </font>&nbsp;');
      $('#dvTable').append(text);
      $('#dvTable').append(' <select> <option id="1">1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option> <option>8</option> </select> ');
      
      var i = "2";
      $('#dvTable').append('<input type="button" id='+ i +' value="x" class="btn btn-danger">');
    } else if(text == "device_3"){
      $('#dvTable').append('<font face="Arial" size="4"> </font> &nbsp;');
      $('#dvTable').append(text);
      $('#dvTable').append(' <select> <option>1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option> <option>8</option> </select> ');
      var i = "3";
      $('#dvTable').append('<input type="button" id='+ i +' value="x" class="btn btn-danger">');
    }
  }); 
});
  
 
$( "#dvTable" ).click(function() {
  //  alert("clicked");
  $(this).remove(); // it will remove entire div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemOptions" class="panel panel-info">

  <div >
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <font face="Arial" size="4" >Select Device:</font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <select id="ddl_device_option">
      <option id="1">device_1</option>
      <option id="2">device_2</option>
      <option id="3">device_3</option>
      <option id="4">device_4</option>
      <option id="5">device_5</option>
      <option id="6">device_6</option>
      <option id="7">device_7</option>
      <option id="8">device_8</option>
      <option id="9">device_9</option>
    </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input  id = "btnAddItem" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-warning"> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dvTable">

</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you are currently doing?  Why is it not working?

Comment: @Martin for now it will remove entire div instead of removing dropdownlist one by one.

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet from the code in your question, using the  `<>` button after clicking on `edit` below your question.

Comment: *for now it will remove entire div instead of removing dropdownlist one by one* Well, that's what you're telling it to do.

Comment: Your code creates duplicate ids, which are not allowed. That makes your HTML invalid. **`id` must be unique per-document.** Aside from that, wrap the elements you are adding in a `div`, which then allows you to remove that `div` instead of every single element you're adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.  The first is that your click event fires on the wrong element:

```
$( "#dvTable" ).click(function() {
  //  alert("clicked");
  $(this).remove(); // it will remove entire div
});
```

This will cause *any click* on `#dvTable` to delete `#dvTable`.  This is clearly not what you want.

However, simply adding the `click` event to the `#dvTable > input[type=button]` selector won't work correctly.  The way you build your new elements means that your dynamic HTML is buggy.

I've modified your HTML output to this:

```
var newElement;   
newElement = '<div>';
newElement += '<font face="Arial" size="4">&nbsp;' + text + '</font>'
newElement += '<select id="test"> <option>1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option> <option>8</option> </select>'
var i = "1";
newElement += '<input type="button" id='+ i +' value="x" class="btn btn-danger" >';
newElement += '</div>';
$('#dvTable').append(newElement);
```

This builds the text for the new element and *wraps it in a `div`*.  It then adds the whole element at once to `#dvTable`.

It then becomes much easier to remove the item you added.  Your code then becomes:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dvTable > div > select + input[type=button]', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Essentially, when you click on *any* button that is under a `div` under `#dvTable`, it removes the *parent* element, which is the `div`.  This removes all of the dynamic content you added previously, instead of only part of it.

Take a look at the following working snippet showing this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAddItem").click(function(){
    var text = $('#ddl_device_option').val();  
    if(text == "device_1"){
      var newElement;
      
      newElement = '<div>';
      newElement += '<font face="Arial" size="4">&nbsp;' + text + '</font>'
      newElement += '<select id="test"> <option>1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option> <option>8</option> </select>'
      var i = "1";
      newElement += '<input type="button" id='+ i +' value="x" class="btn btn-danger" >';
      newElement += '</div>';
      
      $('#dvTable').append(newElement);
    }
  }); 
});
  
 
$(document).on('click', '#dvTable > div > select + input[type=button]', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemOptions" class="panel panel-info">

  <div >
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <font face="Arial" size="4" >Select Device:</font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <select id="ddl_device_option">
      <option id="1">device_1</option>
      <option id="2">device_2</option>
      <option id="3">device_3</option>
      <option id="4">device_4</option>
      <option id="5">device_5</option>
      <option id="6">device_6</option>
      <option id="7">device_7</option>
      <option id="8">device_8</option>
      <option id="9">device_9</option>
    </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input  id = "btnAddItem" type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-warning"> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dvTable">

</div>
```

Note: I removed `device_2` and `device_3` from the code to show you an *example* of this working.  You can fix those based on the code I've provided here.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$("#dvTable").click()`, then variable `this` is the `#dvTable` itself. You telling the script to remove this entire div. What you should do is wrap the select and button in another div and do something like:

```js
$("#dvTable button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

or

```js
$("#dvTable").on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: This will not work.  The added elements are not grouped together, so removing the `parent` will still remove `#dvTable`.

Comment: I said he should wrap it in another div, so it should remove only the select and button :)

Answer (score 0):

You can used like below. Give one id to drop down list as a "test"

```
$('#test').children('option:(:last)').remove();

$('#test').find('option:last-child').remove();
```

Above code automatically remove last option of drop down.